# Is their a way to filter solr results based on previous score results of the same call?

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I want to return results from a solr call and filter them based on the score difference between the first call results

for example

first call solr would return 
Result    Score
a         22
b         5
c         3

Filter should return only the first row (a  22) since the difference betwenn the score of a and b is more than 10.

Comment: The absolute score value is usually not something you can rely on for useful metrics. What is the actual use case you're trying to solve?

Comment: @MatsLindh Actually i am using an absolute score for my usecase which is searching in multiple fields and each match should have a different score to enforce a specific sorting criteria. It is working perfectly except for fuzzy search (which is having the least score) So with some use cases i am getting results of correct matches which has high scores followed immediately with results with a relatively big deference in the score in which i would like to filter out but i cannot specify a static number for filtering that's why the filtering should be within the context of each search query.